# how to install plugins of GStreamer in windows

Tags: windows, gstreamer

I am not able to find out any way to install any GStreamer plugins in my windows 7 desktop.
It only showing **No such element or plugin 'ximagesrc'**

Answer (score 1):

`ximagesrc` is an element for Linux. There is no way to install this plugin on Windows.